# Instagram API. Can only return info about myself but nothing else

Tags: instagram-api

api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?access_token=[MY-ACCESS-TOKEN]&q=[lofarabia]

Hi there. I authenticated myself to use the Instagram api and i when i call the above rest endpoint using my profile name as the accountName i can get account detail information returned about my own profile.

```
{
"meta": {
    "code": 200
},
"data": [
    {
        "username": "lofarabia",
        "bio": "Java, Java Java",
        "website": "http://www.javarocks.co.uk",
        "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/blahblah.jpg",
        "full_name": "Lawrence of Arabia ",
        "id": "390070249"
    }
]
```

}

But when i try and make the same call but pass in someone elses profile name as the accname i get back the following

```
 {
"meta": {
    "code": 200
},
"data": []
}
```

What am i missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This has answered my question

https://medium.com/@emersonthis/instagram-on-websites-the-new-landscape-62c91d733894#.1qaslwuft